# Finding the Intersection between two Vectors

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, intersection

And I'm doing pretty good in fact I found the intersection and think I have the right code. Only problem is that it doesn't seem to print out the last value.

So if I have two sets:

`9 12 7 8 1 19 11 2 14`

`15 10 8 2 5 16 14 7 19 0 11 3 13 18 9 17 1 12`

My code will produce the following output:

```
1
2
7
8
9
11
12
14
```

But the right intersection of the sets should be:

```
1
2
7
8
9
11
12
14
19
```

So, my code doesn't print out the last value and I can't find out why.

```
void findIntersection(vector<int> A, vector<int> B)
{
    vector<int> intersection;
    int n1 = A.size();
    int n2 = B.size();
    int i = 0, j =0;
    while(i <= n1 && j <= n2)
    {
        if(A[i] > B[j])
        {
            j++;
        }
        else if( B[j] > A[i])
        {
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            intersection.push_back(A[i]);
            i++;
            j++;
        }
    }

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i <= intersection.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << intersection[i] << endl;
    }
}

void slowintersect(vector<vector<int> > v)
{
    vector<int> vec;
    vector<int> c;
    int store_0;

    int row = 0;
    for(size_t j =0; j < v.at(row).size(); j++)
    {
        store_0 = v[row][j];
        c.push_back(store_0);
    }

    for(size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        for(size_t k = 0; k < v.at(i).size(); k++)
        {
            vec.push_back(k);
        }
    }

    findIntersection(c, vec);
}
```

Comment: C++ has many nice [algorithms](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm), for example [`std::set_intersection`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection).

Comment: I know they're wonderful! Unfortunately my professor doesn't think the same. =[

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you do not want to use the C++ standard algorithm.

Couple of things.
1. Your algorithm shall work only if both vectors are initially sorted. Are they?
2. You shouldn't access vector[vector.size()] element as it is out of bounds.

My second point means:

```
while(i <= n1 && j <= n2)
```

Change this to

```
while(i < n1 && j < n2)
```

And change the following

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i <= intersection.size(); i++)
```

to

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < intersection.size(); i++)
```

Also, **MOST IMPORTANT ERROR!!!!**

```
for(size_t k = 0; k < v.at(i).size(); k++)
            {
                vec.push_back(k);

            }
```

Change it to:

```
for(size_t k = 0; k < v[i].size(); k++)
            {
                vec.push_back(v[i][k]);

            }
```

Comment: My bad yes, both vectors have been sorted in another function, and could you elaborate on the second point?

Comment: You shouldn't provide a full working code ready for a copy/paste since it's an Assignment! :P

Comment: @user2757849 Please see my update. Your most important error has been highlighted.

Comment: @user9000 OP has already shown his code. I have just applied corrections to it.

Comment: I know but there's no point providing this, id rather just give him information on how to solve his problems and no code at all.  but whatever, though, I ain't here to fight about helping people.

Comment: @user9000 Code deleted.

Answer (score 7):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>

set<int> intersect;
set_intersection(s1.begin(),s1.end(),s2.begin(),s2.end(), // sorted!
                  std::inserter(intersect,intersect.begin()));
```

### [example](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_intersection/)

if you don't want `std::algorithm`, there are several errors in your code. i.e:

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i <= intersection.size(); i++)
                           ^
                        should be <
```

here is an important error:

```
int i = 0, j =0;
while(i <= n1 && j <= n2)
{        ^          ^
         <          <
    if(A[i] > B[j])
    {
        j++;
```

you will skip all n-1 A elements if A[0] is greater than each B element, and end the loop

Comment: [set_intersection](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection) requires the range to be sorted.

Comment: Ok I don't want set_intersection but thank you I actually took that approach in another algorithm and it worked beautifully, So I just implemented what you said on the bottom and unfortunately I still can't get the last output, still only goes up to 14.

Answer (score 1):

Your `while` co dition is broken. You must continue until *both* indexes are at the end. Currently you stop when one of the indexes has reached the end.

When you fix that, you also must ensure that you don't increase `i` beyond `n1`; same for `j` and `n2`.

While you are developing you should rather use `vector.at(i)` instead of `vector[i]` to enable safety checks.